# speed problems with query showing multiple products with same model

Tags: mysql

With following query I get all products listed with more then 1 same products_model.
Exact what I want only... the speed of the query sucks. It takes 26 sec. avarage to get the data on screen. products_model is indexed.
Have no idea how to speed up this query. Maybe someone of you can help me.
Thanks in advanced.

```
SELECT products_model 
FROM products
WHERE manufacturers_id = 239
  AND products_model IN (
      SELECT products_model
      FROM 
         products_guede 
      GROUP BY
         products_model
      HAVING count(products_model) > 1
    )
```

Comment: do you have any right to modify the index? maybe you should check with a dba to apply an index for products_model. Otherwise for the query itself, you should use a join instead. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT p.products_model
FROM products p INNER JOIN products_guede pg
 ON p.products_model = pg.products_model
WHERE p.manufacturers_id = 239
GROUP BY p.products_model
HAVING COUNT(products_model) > 1
```

And following index might help you.

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD INDEX(manufacturers_id, products_model);
ALTER TABLE products_guede ADD INDEX( products_model);
```

Comment: Correct! I forgot both indexes. It works now quick only 117ms.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92a974/1)

```
select
  p.products_model
from
  products p
  left join products_guede pg 
    on p.products_model = pg.products_model
-- where manufacturers_id in (239,...) 
group by p.products_model
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: just add whatever condition you want in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, checking each single query result against all columns of another table would take such a long time with huge tables (more than 1,000 data records)

Try this instead:

```
SELECT count(*) as model_occurence, products_model
FROM products_guede
INNER JOIN products on products.products_model = products_guede.products_model
WHERE manufacturers_id = 239
GROUP BY products_guede.products_model;
```